# Como acceder a este JSON en Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

buenas tardes, estoy intentando acceder a este JSON con Javascript usando JSON.parse(json);

```
json = '{"ticket":{"Test":{"Nombre":"PRUEBAS","Sitio":"PRUEBAS","Tomo":"43","Cobro":"10629970","Fecha":"08\/05\/2019","Hora":"08:51 PM","MontoTotal":"4.00","Tipo":"Original"},"Causas":[[{"Nombre":"NACIONAL","Codigo":"Codigo","Hora":": 08:51 AM","Monto":"4.00","Hojas":[[{"Hoja":"1","Letras":"55"},{"Hoja":"2","Letras":"23"}]]}]],"Footer":{"Footer1":null,"Footer2":null}}}';
```

Unicamente he podido acceder al indicie Test y manejar todos los items que hay dentro de el usando json.ticket.Test.Nombre.

Pero cuando intento acceder al indice Causas, lo unico que recibo es Undefined.

Lo estoy intentando con json.ticket.Test.Causas[numero del indice]

Agradesco cualquier tipo de ayuda!

Comment: Puedes probar con:  `json.ticket.Causas[0][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hasta donde pude ver Causas no esta donde lo estas pidiendo aki te pongo una foto para que lo entiendas mejor[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiere decir que para acceder a **Causas**, seria a travez de:

```
console.log(json.ticket.Causas);
```

Y como en Causas lo que hay es un arreglo de arreglos para obtener la primera causa seria con:

```
console.log(json.ticket.Causas[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A veces el manejo de los **JSON** puede llegar a ser algo confuso, sobre todo si, como en tu caso, tienen una considerable profundidad. En estos casos suelo usar alguna herramienta Web de parseado de **JSON**, que además de mostrarlo más claro, te sirve para validar si el JSON está bien formado.

```
{  
   "ticket":{  
      "Test":{  
         "Nombre":"PRUEBAS",
         "Sitio":"PRUEBAS",
         "Tomo":"43",
         "Cobro":"10629970",
         "Fecha":"08\/05\/2019",
         "Hora":"08:51 PM",
         "MontoTotal":"4.00",
         "Tipo":"Original"
      },
      "Causas":[  
         [  
            {  
               "Nombre":"NACIONAL",
               "Codigo":"Codigo",
               "Hora":": 08:51 AM",
               "Monto":"4.00",
               "Hojas":[  
                  [  
                     {  
                        "Hoja":"1",
                        "Letras":"55"
                     },
                     {  
                        "Hoja":"2",
                        "Letras":"23"
                     }
                  ]
               ]
            }
         ]
      ],
      "Footer":{  
         "Footer1":null,
         "Footer2":null
      }
   }
}
```

De esta manera, podrías acceder al nombre de la  causa de la siguiente manera:

```js
json = {"ticket":{"Test":{"Nombre":"PRUEBAS","Sitio":"PRUEBAS","Tomo":"43","Cobro":"10629970","Fecha":"08\/05\/2019","Hora":"08:51 PM","MontoTotal":"4.00","Tipo":"Original"},"Causas":[[{"Nombre":"NACIONAL","Codigo":"Codigo","Hora":": 08:51 AM","Monto":"4.00","Hojas":[[{"Hoja":"1","Letras":"55"},{"Hoja":"2","Letras":"23"}]]}]],"Footer":{"Footer1":null,"Footer2":null}}};

console.log(json.ticket.Causas[0][0].Nombre);
```